# PHP - not instantiable while building [Spatie\Cors\Cors]

Tags: php, laravel, cors

I'm not familiar with CORS. Someone had added it to this project and I don't know to much about it.  I've been trying to deploy a dev version of this project to a live server but I am getting this error.

`Target [Spatie\Cors\CorsProfile\CorsProfile] is not instantiable while building [Spatie\Cors\Cors].`

I haven't found to much info online about this error. I did however come across a thread that said I need to add the provider to my `config/app.php` however this brought me to a new error when using `php artisan` commands.

`Class 'Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider not found`

Now I know it had worked fine in a previous deployment so I'm not sure what is triggering this now. I frankly didn't wanna aimlessly add to much to this guys work because I don't really know what he is using it for and I have been trying to learn what its use is for so I could fix it or reimplement it, but so far I have had no luck. Has anyone have any idea how to solve this issue or where I should start?

**php artisan package:discover**

```
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/cashier
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: tymon/jwt-auth
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`, if did not work, do a `composer update`.

Comment: should I keep the provider in `config/app.php` ? It wasnt there before but was working just fine.

Comment: add the serviceprovider in config/app.php:

`Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,` after, Run this command : `composer update`

Comment: Ok so I added it to `config/app.php` under `providers` , ran `composer dumpautoload` and am still getting the same error. (`Target [Spatie\Cors\CorsProfile\CorsProfile] is not instantiable while building [Spatie\Cors\Cors].`) when refreshing my site. I also cleared my browser cache so that rules that problem out.

Comment: PermissionServiceProvider is for a separate package. Have you run `composer install`?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya I also ran `composer update` and it returned `Nothing to install or update`

Comment: @TravisBritz Yes I ran `composer install` and it didn't work. it returned `Nothing to install or update`

Comment: For the record I have `"spatie/laravel-cors": "^1.3",` in my `composer.json` file

Comment: What version of Laravel is this? `php artisan --version`

Comment: @TravisBritz it is `Laravel Framework 5.5.44`. (my dev environment is the same aswell)

Comment: Try `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Cors\CorsServiceProvider" --tag="config"`

Comment: @TravisBritz `Publishing complete.` but still no luck

Comment: run `php artisan package:discover`

Comment: @N69S I updated my question with the response

Comment: If all else fails you can ping their github repo: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors - I need to get to sleep

Comment: somewhere in your code, you're using `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Permission` instead of `Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission`

Comment: @N69S I did a search through my entire project for `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Permission` no instance of that was found.

Comment: @N69S that's a completely different package than `spatie/laravel-cors`.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, `Target [...] is not instantiable while building [...]` indicates a problem binding to the service container. *Usually* this is caused by the package's ServiceProvider not being registered.

Most packages developed for Laravel 5.5 and above will automatically register their service providers when the `@php artisan package:discover` command is run by composer (it's defined in composer.json in the `post-autoload-dump` scripts). In older Laravel versions you would have needed to manually add the service provider for the package to `config/app.php`.

In this case it looks like the `Spatie\Cors\Cors` middleware is trying to resolve an instance of `Spatie\Cors\CorsProfile\CorsProfile` (which is an *interface*) [from the container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations), and the container doesn't know how to make one. The service provider of this package [binds](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors/blob/0e247545df180ad2e4bc13396567d97b9fbae35d/src/CorsServiceProvider.php#L26) this interface to the config value found in the `cors_profile` setting of `config/cors.php`, so I would check that value first and compare with the defaults shown in the readme of their package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors. There could also be namespace issues such as a mistake in the `use` statement in one of your files.

In your case, adding `Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class` to the `config/app.php` providers array didn't work because *it's a different package*. The same goes for `Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Permission` - Those are all part of `spatie/laravel-permission`, not `spatie/laravel-cors`. The correct service provider for this package would be `Spatie\Cors\CorsServiceProvider::class` if that were the issue, which might be the case if you're on an older version of the package which had not been updated to use the auto-discover feature of Laravel 5.5. However, I think that can be ruled out since it was listed in the `package:discover` output.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.
There is one small difference in my file `'allow_headers'` has `'X-Requested-With',` when the one on github doesn't.

Comment: One question. Would this problem also come about in my localhost? my local version seems fine. I'm wondering if this came about while deploying.

Comment: @jermaynewilliams did you ever figure this out? I just had the exact problem on localhost and it was due to a database permissions problem (I forgot I was still connected through a VPN).

Answer (score 0):

```
Illuminate \ Contracts \ Container \ BindingResolutionException Target [Spatie\Cors\CorsProfile\CorsProfile] is not instantiable while building [Spatie\Cors\Cors].
--Run this command--
php artisan key:generate

If showing ....bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable.
    then create a cache folder in bootstrap folder.
```